# rtl direction doesn't work in jquery simplebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, scrollbar

I need to add scroll bar in left. So, add `direction:'rtl'` option to [jquery simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) scrollbar plugin:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("simple-bar");
new SimpleBar(myElement, {
  autoHide: true,
  direction: 'rtl'
});
```

But in action `rtl` option not work for me. how do can I show scrollbar in left?!

demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvj0nwg9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parameter `data-simplebar-direction='rtl'` to the tag ( `id="simple-bar"` ), and it should look like this:

```
<div id="simple-bar" data-simplebar-direction='rtl'>
...
</div>
```